# How to separate a string in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsstring

I need to get a string that which is in between ( and ). For example I have a string like "name(123)". I need to get the values of 123 which between ( and ).

Comment: the documentation of NSString is helpful. the methods "subStringFromIndex/..ToIndex/..inRange

Comment: Take a look at [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), subsections Finding Characters and Substrings and Dividing Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"name(123)";
NSString *seperatorCharsString = @"()";
NSCharacterSet *seperatorCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:seperatorCharsString];
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:seperatorCharSet];
NSString *number = [components lastObject];
```

Comment: @Black Frog Thanks for pointing out this embarrassing screw up, i'll fix my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a regular expression to extract to the string, you can do that with blocks and NSRegularExpression (since iOS4.0)

Something like this :

```
NSRegularExpression *reg = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\(.*?\))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

[reg enumerateMatchesInString:<YOUR_STRING> options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [<YOUR_STRING> length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    for (int i=0; i < match.numberOfRanges; i++) {
        NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
        NSString *extractedString = [<YOUR_STRING> substringWithRange:range];
    }
}];
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent